# How do I convert .tfw (topographical maps) files either PDF, JPEG or PSD

Tags: geotiff-tiff, convert

How do I convert .tfw (topographical maps) files either PDF, JPEG or PSD on a Mac?

The files are South African topo maps that were originally on a DVD. Files are now saved as per this example - 2628DD_1991_ED3_GEO.tfw. Photoshop does not recognised them and I don't seem to find a program that can convert the file type.

Comment: The "world file" is a 6-line ASCII file, which can be opened with any text editor. So long as the dimensions of the image haven't changed, it can likely be used as-is, though the suffix naming changes with image format.

Comment: This can be answered by a Google search: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file There is no image info in there so it cannot be converted to anything.

Comment: tfw is just the geo-info starting the top left of the image with pixel size/rotation - GIS software then calculates that and works out the extent to fit the image. Photoshop without plugins will no recognise this.

Comment: Do you not also have a file named 2628DD_1991_ED3_GEO.tif?